# How to fix this Gatsby Eslint error: xstate.after(1000)#waitingMachine.batchingNodeMutations

Tags: import, state, gatsby, eslint

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: Event xstate.after(1000)#waitingMachine.batchingNodeMutations"
> was sent to stopped service "waitingMachine". This service has already reached

What can I try? Also I'm getting eslint errors:

import/no-extraneous-dependencies", "import/no-absolute-path" & "global-require" are giving errors since an update last week....

Comment: I also started getting this warning yesterday.  Are you doing SVG animations in any of your components? Mine started after I added some state and effect hooks to trigger some animation, but I don't know if that is related.

Comment: @ncox85 yes i'm using SVG files. I never had this problem... But i will test it with adding state to it.

Still having this issue, my hot-loader doesn't work as supposed. I have to save my files 3x to see any changes, sometimes I have to restart the whole local server. Does someone has any other sollutions yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest update `gatsby@2.24.57` should fix it!

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this error. There are two open issues for it on the Gatsby github:

- [Browser won't hot reload re-compiled sources, broken after `gatsby@2.24.9`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26192)
- [Warning: Event "xstate.after(1000)#waitingMachine.batchingNodeMutations](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26839)

It looks like the problem was introduced with PR #25815. Rolling back to Gatsby 2.24.9 fixed the problem for me and looks like it fixes it for most others, but your mileage may vary.